# Problema al gestionar correos electrónicos y metadatos en Mayan: condición para etiquetar correos electrónicos no funciona como se espera

Tags: django, postgresql, redis, rabbit-mq

Estamos enfrentando un desafío al intentar gestionar múltiples direcciones de correo electrónico y sus metadatos. Actualmente, estamos extrayendo datos de los correos electrónicos y agregando metadatos adicionales para facilitar su administración. Sin embargo, estamos teniendo dificultades para lograr el resultado deseado.

Nuestro objetivo es gestionar varios correos electrónicos que pueden provenir de diversas personas. Para lograr esto, estamos utilizando OCR y etiquetas. Queremos aplicar etiquetas a los correos electrónicos en función de su contenido OCR, y estamos usando la siguiente condición en nuestras plantillas Jinja2:

```
{% if "Microsoft" in workflow_instance.document.ocr_content|join:" " %}True{% endif %}
```

Sin embargo, parece que esta condición no está funcionando según lo esperado. Queremos que la condición verifique si el contenido OCR del documento del correo electrónico contiene la palabra "Microsoft" y, en ese caso, aplicar etiquetas correspondientes.